# Query not working properly for multiple filters,, struggling to debug

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel blade project for an ecommerce store (imagine equipment). we have category filters for different types of equipment as well as spec filters like engine power / capacity etc.

I have two types of spec filters. One called "power" with filter values of < 10 n , 10 n  -20 n, > 20 n.
Another called Capacity with filter values of < 20 g , 20 g - 30 g, > 33 g.
Lets say there are 3 products. Product a with spec values of 8n and 25g.
product b with spec values of  9 n and 33g.
product c with spec values of 12 n and 12 g.

When I clicked the filter checkbox < 20 g it returned all 3 products! it should only return product c. but it worked fine for other filters except > 20 n.
So I guess there is an issue but I can't figure out what exactly.

ProductService.php

```
protected function buildQuery(
    ?string $searchText = '',
    ?Category $category = null,
    ?Collection $categories = null,
    ?Brand $brand = null,
    ?array $categorySpecs = null
): Builder {
    // sleep(1); //to simulate a slow query
    $product = Product::whereLike([
        'title_en', 'title_ar', 'sku',
        'description_en', 'description_ar'
    ], $searchText);

    if ($categories) {
        $product = $product->whereIn('cat_id', $categories->pluck('id'));
    } else {
        $product = $product->when(
            $category,
            function (Builder $query, Category $category) {
                return $query->where(
                    function (Builder $query) use ($category) {
                        return $query->where('cat_id', $category->id)
                            ->orWhereIn(
                                'cat_id',
                                optional($category->children)
                                    ->pluck('id')
                            );
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }

    $product = $product->when(
        $brand,
        function (Builder $query, Brand $brand) {
            return $query->where('company_id', $brand->id);
        }
    );

    $product = $product->when(
        $categorySpecs,
        function (Builder $query, array $categorySpecs) {
            return $query->where(
                function (Builder $query) use ($categorySpecs) {
                    foreach ($categorySpecs as $categorySpec) {
                        $query = $query->orWhereHas(
                            'spec',
                            function (Builder $query) use ($categorySpec) {
                                return $query->where(
                                    'title_en',
                                    $categorySpec['spec_title']
                                );
                            }
                        )->whereHas(
                            'productSpecs',
                            function (Builder $query) use ($categorySpec) {
                                if ($categorySpec['min'] && $categorySpec['max']) {
                                    $query = $query->whereBetween(
                                        'value_calculated',
                                        [
                                            $categorySpec['min'],
                                            $categorySpec['max']
                                        ]
                                    );
                                } elseif ($categorySpec['min']) {
                                    $query = $query->where(
                                        'value_calculated',
                                        '<=',
                                        $categorySpec['min']
                                    );
                                } elseif ($categorySpec['max']) {
                                    $query = $query->where(
                                        'value_calculated',
                                        '>=',
                                        $categorySpec['max']
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }

                    return $query;
                }
            );
        }
    );

    return $product;
}
```

Snapshot of product_spec table

[image]

Snapshot of spec table
[image]

Snapshot of category_spec table
[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems to be, atleast from what I see, the fact you're not using a `WHERE` "group" after this:

```php
foreach ($categorySpecs as $categorySpec) { ... }
```

So, because the query you make inside the foreach starts with a `orWhereHas` it basically means that even if one categorySpec filter is matched the record should be taken (and as I understand you don't want that, you want that a record gets taken from the database ONLY if all the condition specs are matched).

The final code should look like this:

```php
$product = $product->when(
        $categorySpecs,
        function (Builder $query, array $categorySpecs) {
            return $query->where(
                function (Builder $query) use ($categorySpecs) {
                    foreach ($categorySpecs as $categorySpec) {
                        $query = $query->orWhereHas(
                            'spec',
                            function (Builder $query) use ($categorySpec) {
                                return $query->where(
                                    'title_en',
                                    $categorySpec['spec_title']
                                );
                            }
                        )->whereHas(
                            'productSpecs',
                            function (Builder $query) use ($categorySpec) {
                                if ($categorySpec['min'] && $categorySpec['max']) {
                                    $query = $query->whereBetween(
                                        'value_calculated',
                                        [
                                            $categorySpec['min'],
                                            $categorySpec['max']
                                        ]
                                    );
                                } elseif ($categorySpec['min']) {
                                    $query = $query->where(
                                        'value_calculated',
                                        '<=',
                                        $categorySpec['min']
                                    );
                                } elseif ($categorySpec['max']) {
                                    $query = $query->where(
                                        'value_calculated',
                                        '>=',
                                        $categorySpec['max']
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }

                    return $query;
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work, client requirement is such that if one product falls under "10 - 20 n" range from "power" filter and another product falls under "> 33g" for "capacity" filter. if he clicks "10-20n"and "> 33g"... return both products that's why i used orwherehas. 

my issue is when all filters are unchecked and I check just "<22g".. it is returning all products when it should return only the product c. 

its been painful, i cant figure out whats up with certain filters not working right but rest working good

Comment: @ToveC Did you atleast try the code I've posted? It might work

Comment: I said "it didn't work" yes I pasted it in

Comment: @ToveC You can try getting the query that is launched by using `$query->toSql()`, have you already tried that? Looking at the query might help solving these issues. If you post the query here I'll give it a look

Comment: this is when i click "<22g"
"select * from `products` where (`title_en` LIKE ? or `title_ar` LIKE ? or `sku` LIKE ? or `description_en` LIKE ? or `description_ar` LIKE ?) and (`cat_id` = ? or `cat_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) and (exists (select * from `specs` inner join `product_spec` on `product_spec`.`spec_id` = `specs`.`id` where `products`.`id` = `product_spec`.`product_id` and `title_en` = ?) and exists (select * from `product_spec` where `products`.`id` = `product_spec`.`product_id` and `value_calculated` <= ?))